# about jquery ajax, the php file had run but the success function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**my html file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#thumb').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upvote.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#test").html("hello");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                $('#test').html(msg);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**upvote.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
global $error;
global $conn;
include("connect.php");
$id    = $_REQUEST['id'];
$uid   = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sql   = "SELECT voted FROM voted WHERE questionid=$id AND uid=$uid";
$tot   = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($tot);
if ($total == 0) {
    $query  = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO voted(questionid, voted, uid) VALUES('$id','true','$uid')");
    $query2 = "UPDATE question SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE questionid = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $query3 = "SELECT vote FROM question WHERE questionid = 'id'";
    $ql     = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
    $res    = mysqli_fetch_array($ql);
    $vote   = $res['vote'];

    json_encode($vote);
} else {
    $false = "false";
    json_encode($false);
}
?>
```

The problem is that when $('#thumb') is clicked, the php file is running as I can find the sql in it is executed and I can find the record in the database MySQL, however, I want to have some function to run in the success function, and I have tried to try $("#test").html("hello"); and it doesn't work. Any advice for that, thanks!

Comment: Is the `#test` element present on the page? Instead of using that to check the response, try checking your networking tab. You will find your AJAX response that is returned to your browser in there.

Comment: If the HTML is above the PHP code then that's your issue. You need to return *only* JSON formatted data from the request. You need to either amend the logic flow, or put the PHP that deals with the request in its own page

Comment: It responds with nothing? does it get to the error part?

Comment: Use console.log('hello'); instead $('#test').html(msg); or make sure that #test is created, maybe the success is working but you can't see #test.

Comment: add `echo` OR `return` before `json_encode($vote)` and `json_encode($false)`.

Comment: first add echo in php file for return json data
second add async: false in your ajax option

Answer (score 0):

Try `try {} catch () {}` for finding error

Like This:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "upvote.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
  type: "get",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    try {
      $("#test").html("hello");
    } catch (e) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
      msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
      msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
      msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
      msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
      msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
      msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
      msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    $('#test').html(msg);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upvote.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success '+data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert('error '+exception);
            },
        });
});
```